# how to push ejabberd to heroku

Tags: heroku, ejabberd

I have cloned it into dir ejabberd. Ran the following commands.

```
./autogen.sh
./configure 
make rel
```

made a Procfile

```
web: ./rel/ejabberd/bin/ejabberdctl start
```

with the following line it.

```
heroku create -buildpack https :// github .com/archaelus/heroku-buildpack-erlang.git
```

then did 
git push heroku master

its gives me the following error

> root@Anubhav:/home/anubhav/new/ejabberd# git push heroku master
>   Counting objects: 25255, done.
>   Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
>   Compressing objects: 100% (5322/5322), done.
>   Writing objects: 100% (25255/25255), 13.78 MiB | 167.00 KiB/s, done.
>   Total 25255 (delta 19874), reused 25251 (delta 19872)
>   remote: Compressing source files... done.
>   remote: Building source:
>   remote:
>   remote: -----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
>   remote:
>   remote:  !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
>   remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack
>   remote:       to use for this application automatically.
>   remote: See https: // devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
>   remote:
>   remote: Verifying deploy...
>   remote:
>   remote: !   Push rejected to infinite-retreat-6912.
>   remote: 
>   To https: //git.heroku.com/infinite-retreat-6912.git
>    ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'https: //git.heroku.com/infinite-retreat-6912.git'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: given Mickael comment that it would be difficult maybe try XMPP server in Java (looks like it's supported by Heroku), for example Tigase XMPP Server (https://tigase.net) or OpenFire?

Answer (score -1):

I do not think ejabberd can be used as is on Heroku. There is several dependancies in C and lib required that are probably not available on Heroku. At least it has never been tested but I would be surprised if it worked.

Comment: so what other options do I have instead of heroku considering the fact that I am using Rails ??

Comment: Well, any full server, like for example Amazon AWS. Rails is not a limitation here as you can install Rails on any Linux server.